# Laravel 5 Fatal Error: class not found exception cannot access the model classes when it is inside a folder

Tags: php, laravel-5, propel

Here is my application structure,

```
my-first-app
   |    
   |-app
     |
     | -Commands
     | -Console
     | -Events
     | -Http
     | -models(custom define folder)
        |
        |-Base(folder)
        |   |
        |   | -StuDetails.php
        |   | -StuDetailsQuery.php
        |
        |-Map(foder)
        |-StuDetails.php
        |-StuDetailsQuery.php
```

Actually I'm using propel ORM to retrieve data from the database.
I created my model classes inside the folder **models**.
Then I tried to access **StudetailsQuery** class inside my **pageController** class which is inside http folder extended as Controller.

Here it is :

```
<?php
namespace App\models\propel;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


use Base\StuDetailsQuery;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class pagesController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {
        $stu= StuDetailsQuery::create()->find();
        return view('pages.index', compact('stu'));
    }
```

But I get error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Base\StuDetailsQuery' not
>   found in
>   /var/www/my-first-app/app/Http/Controllers/pagesController.php

I tried;

- composer dump-autoload
- adding following lines to composer.json file

  "autoload": {
      "psr-4":{
              "propel\": "app/models/propel/"
          }}

but nothing goes fine for me.. Any suggestions please ??

Answer (score 1):

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/models/propel"
        ]
```

this solved my problem... :)

Comment: You don't really need to add these lines in autoload. I noticed your namespace are incorrect. Laravel 5 is smart enough to load your classes once their namespaces are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting similar missing class errors. Although I follow the laracast autoloading examples in [You Must Use Composer laracast](https://laracasts.com/lessons/you-must-use-composer#) completely (including the modification of composer.json), I get stuck with a missing class error.

In watching the videos I notices jeffery way uses a \ occasionally before the object name..... I don't know why but in frustration I added it, and it worked for me.

In summary I find I have to use a "\" before the object, like this:

new \Bar;

I hope this helps, and if someone can help me understand what is going on please let us know.